# what`s wrong with this code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I write this but it doesnt work, can`t find the error.
this server side code get the the variable $cpu & $display and use it in select from the data base. when the variable is not important "*" will be sent.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid Data";
    exit;
}

if ($action == "read")
{
    readData();
}

function connectToDatabase()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project_pro");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    return $connection;
}

function readData()
{
    $connection = connectToDatabase();
    $cpu = $_REQUEST['cpu'];
    $display = $_REQUEST['display'];
```

This is the part that problem exists:

```
 $sql = "Select * From phones WHERE";

if ($cpu == "*")
{
}
else
{
    $sql+= " phone_cpu='$cpu'";
}

if ($display == "*")
{
}
else
{
    $sql+= " AND phone_display='$display'";
}

$output = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $record = array();
    $record['phone_id'] = $row['phone_id'];
    $record['phone_cpu'] = $row['phone_cpu'];
    $output[] = $record;
}

echo json_encode($output);
mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Well, it's very difficult to read due to lack of proper indentation, for one... :p

Comment: += is javascript, not php! :). Concatenation in php is .=

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concatenation operator in PHP is  `.`  not `+`. So change `+=` to `.=`.

Comment: + the fact he is trying to get $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) when he never executed the query..